# Script not finishing and error deletes the ranges that already ran

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For some reason this script will run through exactly how I want it to. Then it will continue to load, then delete half the ranges that I have put into the cells and come up with the error:

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRange')

newSheet

@ New sheet.gs:11"

Why would this happen if the script runs perfectly? The getRange is reading in line 11 or it wouldn't run the script correctly at first. I tried putting this into a new script window to see if it is just a fluke but that did not help.

```
function newSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const  templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
var sheetName = templateSheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName("F"+sheetName);
var ods = ss.getSheetByName("F"+sheetName);
var ds = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1meEEfjXuOKQ3jCZi2wwmvz7CH83crsPzgnhOEC0rDhI");
var sheet = ds.getSheets(); 
for (var i=0;i<=sheet.length;i++){
  var sheets = sheet[i]
  var range = sheets.getRange("A1").getValue();//this is the spot that is getting the error
  var label = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var values1 = sheets.getRange("A9:B14").getValues();
  var values2 = sheets.getRange("G8").getValues();
  var values3 = sheets.getRange("A17:A22").getValues();
  var values4 = sheets.getRange("A25:A32").getValues();
  var values5 = sheets.getRange("A34:G44").getValues();
  var values6 = sheets.getRange("A45:A49").getValues();
  var values7 = sheets.getRange("A52:A58").getValues();
  var values8 = sheets.getRange("A62:A67").getValues();
  var values9 = sheets.getRange("E69:E74").getValues();
  var values10 = sheets.getRange("E100:E103").getValues();
  var values11 = sheets.getRange("H100:H101").getValues();
  if(range==label){
    ods.getRange("A9:B14").setValues(values1);
    ods.getRange("G8").setValues(values2);
    ods.getRange("A17:A22").setValues(values3);
    ods.getRange("A25:A32").setValues(values4);
    ods.getRange("A34:G44").setValues(values5);
    ods.getRange("A45:A49").setValues(values6);
    ods.getRange("A52:A58").setValues(values7);
    ods.getRange("A62:A67").setValues(values8);
    ods.getRange("E69:E74").setValues(values9);
    ods.getRange("E100:E103").setValues(values10);
    ods.getRange("H100:H101").setValues(values11);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: replace ```i <= sheet.length ``` by ```i < sheet.length```

Comment: Thanks that took away the error from coming up! Unfortunately though, for some reason values7, values8, values9, values10 and values11 are still showing up at first and then when the script loads and completes they disappear. But values1, values2, values3, values4, values5 and values6 still stay on the final sheet.

Comment: Has anyone else run into this problem before? The script takes about 20 seconds to run and works perfectly. But then continues to load for another minute or so. Then deletes the aforementioned values. I have tried separating the scripts to run one after another in the same function to see if it is just too long and completely separating the script into two separate functions. This happens every time no matter how I change it. Does anyone have any ideas?